# JS/jQuery - animated random name picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a raffle ticket picking script using JS and jQuery.

So far so good - my script works. Now however I'd like to make it much more visual so that we can run it in assembly.

I have a JS Object which takes the following format:

```
var TempObj = { 'Student_ID' : i, 'Student_Name' : data.users[i].Student_Name };
RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[Count] = TempObj;
```

I'm then using this code to randomly select one of the students:

```
$('button#random').click( function() {
    // "Total" is just the array length
    var Num = Math.floor(Math.random() * Total+1);
    Num--;

    // prove that the system has picked a random number out of the list
    alert("Random number out of " + Total + " is..." + Num);

    // find the array entry where the key is our random "Num"
    for (var i in RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray) {
        if (i == Num) {
            // we've found our entry, now we need more information about the corresponding student
            var TutorGroup = '';

            Frog.API.get('timetable.getClasses',
            {
                'params': {'student': RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[i].Student_ID },
                'onSuccess': function(data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        if (data[i].subject.name == "Tut Period") {
                            TutorGroup = data[i].name.replace("/Tp", "");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            // print out the student's information - he or she is the winner!
            alert("Ticket number " + Num + " in the LEAP database belongs to...\n\n\n" + RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[i].Student_Name.toUpperCase() + " (" + TutorGroup + ")");
        }
    }
} );
```

I would like to - very briefly - display each student's name until the ticket has been picked (i.e. `RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[Num]` has been found), then I'd like it to stop and increase the font size (and probably say WINNER! above it or something).

Is this possible, and relatively simple, using jQuery?

**EDIT**

I have tried the following code, which simply displays a single name. Where am I going wrong?

```
$('button#random').click( function() {
    var Num = Math.floor(Math.random() * Total);

    for (var i in RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray) {

        if (typeof RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[i] === 'object' && typeof RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[i] !== null) {

            $('#display').queue( function() { 
                $(this).text(RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[i].Student_Name.toUpperCase()).show().delay(250); 
                $(this).dequeue();
            } );

        }

        if (i == Num) {
            var TutorGroup = '';

            Frog.API.get('timetable.getClasses',
            {
                'params': {'student': RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[i].Student_ID },
                'onSuccess': function(data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        if (data[i].subject.name == "Tut Period") {
                            TutorGroup = data[i].name.replace("/Tp", "");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            break;
        }
    }
} );
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've something working for you available on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/63hug/. I've removed irrelevant code for the demo, and added some improvements. Look at the code to learn more.

```
var students = [
    { 'Student_ID': 0, 'Student_Name': "one" },
    { 'Student_ID': 1, 'Student_Name': "two" },
    { 'Student_ID': 2, 'Student_Name': "three" },
    { 'Student_ID': 3, 'Student_Name': "four" },
    { 'Student_ID': 4, 'Student_Name': "five" },
    { 'Student_ID': 5, 'Student_Name': "six" },
    { 'Student_ID': 6, 'Student_Name': "seven" },
];

var $display = $("#display");

$('#random').click(function(){
    var total = students.length,
        selected = Math.floor( Math.random() * total ),
        i = 0;

    console.log( "selected", selected );
    $display.animate( {"font-size": "12px"}, 0 );

    // improvement: use a for loop, instead of a for..in
    for (i=0; i<total; i++) {

        console.log( "for", i );
        // here is the trick, use an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)
        // see http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/
        setTimeout((function(i){
            return function(){
                // code here will be delayed
                console.log( "timeout", i );
                $display.text( students[i].Student_Name.toUpperCase() );
                if( i === selected ) {
                    $display.animate( {"font-size": "30px"}, "fast" );
                }
            };
        }(i)), i*250);

        // improvement: triple equal sign, always !
        if( i === selected ) {
            // code here will execute immediately
            break;
        }
    }

});
```

You could learn more about Javascript **variable hoisting** here http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.

Also, you should check the point 4 of this list of common Javascript confusions http://tobyho.com/2011/11/16/7-common-js-mistakes-or-confusions/

Hope that'll help :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question you want something like this:
Enter this before the number comparison.

```
$('#nameDisplay').text(RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[i].Student_Name.toUpperCase()).show().delay(300);
```

Enter this inside the `if statement` just before/instead of the `alert` :

```
$('#nameDisplay').animate({'font-size': 36}, 1500, function() {
    $(this).prepend('<span>!!! WINNER !!!</span>');
});
```

`nameDisplay`should be some kind of (hidden) element on your page, styled like you prefer.
Try experimenting with the `CSS` and the animation functions to get a good looking result for the inserted span and the `nameDisplay`element.

Comment: Hi @jb10210, I'd like to give you the answer but I can't test it because of this odd issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485087

Comment: Resolved that issue now! However, your code isn't actually listing through the students, it's just showing one then appending the WINNER in an animated fashion.

Comment: instead of appending/prepending names to the div you can insert text into a div using innerHTML.  innerHTML is read/write so it will destroy whatever is inside the div when it writes to the div

Answer (score 0):

Okay,so you'd like the program to pick a random number between 1 and (total number of students) which will be the winning student. This number is tied to the student's id numbers, so if #45 is randomly picked, student #45 wins.

Seems like you have this bit working already, so next you'd like a sort of slot machine lottery spinner to flip through names and "make a show" of picking the winning number. Likely, the winning number will be picked completely separate of the lottery animation, no reason to make the random number picking take longer than needed (it's only one line of code, after all).

So for your animation, why not just loop through each of the entries in your student list, display them each one or two times one right after the other and then on the third loop it stops on the winning name and emphasizes it accordingly. For example: Mark, Jane, Dave, mark Jane, Dave, Mark, JANE IS THE WINNER!! Obviously animated & styled however you like it.

In short, the answer you seek is in picking the winner, not displaying it right away, then looping all of the names a set number of times and finally landing on the winner. Hopefully that gets you in the right direction without straight out doing the programming for you :)

Answer (score 0):

### Small improvement (skip if you want)

First thing, to point out an improvement in your code:

```
for (var i in RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray) {
    if (i == Num) {      
    //Do stuff with RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[i]
    } 
 }
```

I suggest you do:

```
//Do stuff with RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[Num]
```

No need to needlessly loop (unless you want to have an `else` statement out there as well.

### Back to the question :)

Let's say you've already chosen the winner and stored the index in `Num`. Have a div with `id="winner"` which contains the winner! block, and a div with `id=studentName` to hold the flashing names of students. Both should be hidden.

Now, do this:

```
var flashDelay=100; //number of milliseconds to flash each name
var flashTimes=50; //Flash a random username this many times

var lastStudent=-1; //holds the last student displayed to avoid awkward repeats
function flashStudent(){
var randStudent=Math.floor(Math.random() * Total+1);
if(Num==randStudent||Num==lastStudent){
   flashStudent();   //don't show the winner till the end. Also don't repeat students immediately
}else{
   lastStudent=Num; 
   flashTimes--; //decrement count
   $("#studentName").css("display","block") //display if hidden
   $("winner").html(RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[randStudent].Student_Name); //show name
   if(flashTimes==0){
    clearInterval(flashNames);
     $("#studentName").css("display","block") //display if hidden
     $("#studentName").css("display","block") //display if hidden
     $("#studentName").html(RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[Num].Student_Name);         
   }
}
}
var flashNames=setInterval(flashStudent,flashTimes) //make the method repeat evert flashTimes milliseconds
```

I suggest an even better one where it "slows to a halt" like a roulette wheel:

```
var flashDelay=10; //number of milliseconds to initially flash each name
var flashIncrement=10 //number of milliseconds to increment the delay by each time
var flashTimes=50; //Flash a random username this many times

var lastStudent=-1; //holds the last student displayed to avoid awkward repeats
function flashStudent(){
var randStudent=Math.floor(Math.random() * Total+1);
if(Num==randStudent||Num==lastStudent){
   flashStudent();   //don't show the winner till the end. Also don't repeat students immediately
}else{
   lastStudent=Num; 
   flashTimes--; //decrement count
   $("#studentName").css("display","block") //display if hidden
   $("winner").html(RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[randStudent].Student_Name); //show name
   if(flashTimes==0){
     $("#studentName").css("display","block") //display if hidden
     $("#studentName").css("display","block") //display if hidden
     $("#studentName").html(RewardPurchases.PurchasesArray[Num].Student_Name);         
   }else{
     
     setTimeout(flashStudent,flashDelay); //set timeout for next name
     flashDelay+=flashIncrement; //increment delay
   }
}
}
```

I haven't fully tested this--I'll make a test array tomorrow and do it.